# Is it possible to constrain the values of an array with Typescript to a given subset of string values?

Tags: arrays, typescript

Consider:

```
enum allowedValues {'x','y'}

export interface X {
  evaluation: string[]; // TODO: how to constrain to contain only the values 'x' or 'y';
}
```

I tried declaring `evaluation` as the enum: `evaluation: shownEvaluation[];`
I also tried `evaluation: keyof allowedValues;`

Is it possible to constrain the values of an array with Typescript to a given subset of string values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! You need to declare a union type for the keys:

```
type allowedValues = 'x' | 'y';

export interface X {
    evaluation: allowedValues[];
}
```